# How to prevent Flutter multiple Tab Reloads

Tags: flutter, dart

For the experience, Add `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` in Tab page should be prevent data loss when reload.
[image]

Change it to Room Tab and go back to floor tab, the data still exits.
[image]
[image]

But when I click the "main block" sub tab and go back to other, the "Block" input will be missing

[image]
[image]

Am I using a wrong method to handle multiple tab?

Here is the sources code

This is the main page

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import './tab1.dart';
import './tab1SubTab1.dart';

class TabPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabPage createState() => _TabPage();
}

class _TabPage extends State<TabPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
    TextEditingController doorNumberController = new TextEditingController();
  List<Widget> _checkingForm = <Widget>[];
  List<Widget> _subTab1 = <Widget>[];
  int bottomTabSelect=0;
  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(text: 'Room'),
    Tab(text: 'Floor'),
  ];

  int _checkingIndex = 1;

  void _addChecking() {
    _checkingForm = List.from(_checkingForm)
      ..add(Tab1());

    setState(() {
      _checkingIndex += 1;
    });
  }
  
  void _addSubTab1() {
    _subTab1 = List.from(_subTab1)
      ..add(Tab1SubTab1());
    setState(() {
 
    });
  }

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
    _addChecking();
    _addSubTab1();
  }

 @override
 void dispose() {
   _tabController.dispose();
   super.dispose();
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: myTabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
            children: [
              ListView(
                children: <Widget>[  
                  Text('Add the room number',textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                      fontSize: 25),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle,color: Colors.lightBlue),
                    onPressed: () {
                        _addChecking();
                      },
                    ),   
                    Column(
                      children:_checkingForm,
                  ),    
                ]
              ),
              ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child: new Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: 50.0,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.lightBlue),
                    child:new Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            print("Container clicked");
                            setState(() {
                              bottomTabSelect=0;
                            });
                          },
                          child:Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  if(bottomTabSelect==0)
                                  Text(
                                    'Main Block',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 30.0,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  if(bottomTabSelect!=0)                                  
                                  Text(
                                    'Main Block',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 22.0,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              )
                            )
                          ),
                          GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            print("Container clicked");
                            setState(() {
                              bottomTabSelect=1;
                            });
                          },                          
                          child:Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  if(bottomTabSelect==1)
                                  Text(
                                    'Other',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 30.0,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  if(bottomTabSelect!=1)                                  
                                  Text(
                                    'Other',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 22.0,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              )
                            )
                          ),                        
                        ]
                      )
                    //child: new Text(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toString()),
                    )
                  ), 
                    Text('Floor:', textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                      fontSize: 25),
                    ),
                      Container(              
                            width: 250.0,
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: doorNumberController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                labelText: 'Floor:',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),  
                      if(bottomTabSelect==1)
                        Column(
                          children:_subTab1,
                        )
                    ]
              ),
            ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the Tab page:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class Tab1 extends StatefulWidget {

  String input;
  @override
  _Tab1 createState() => _Tab1();
  
}

class _Tab1 extends State<Tab1> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  TextEditingController doorNumberController = new TextEditingController();
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //doorNumberController.text=input;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Card(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
                Row( 
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Room:', textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                      fontSize: 25),
                    ),
                      Container(              
                            width: 250.0,
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: doorNumberController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                labelText: 'Room number:',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),                  
                    ]
                  ),
                Row(
                  children:<Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
                      color: Colors.blue,
                        onPressed: () {
                          print(doorNumberController.text);
                      },
                    ),      
                  ]
                ) 
          ]
        )
      );
  }
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Sub Tab:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class Tab1SubTab1 extends StatefulWidget {

  String input;
  @override
  _Tab1SubTab1 createState() => _Tab1SubTab1();
  
}

class _Tab1SubTab1 extends State<Tab1SubTab1> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  TextEditingController blockController = new TextEditingController();
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Card(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
                Row( 
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Block:', textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                        fontSize: 25),
                      ),                
                    ]
                  ),
                  Container(              
                    width: 250.0,
                    child: TextField(
                    controller: blockController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Block:',
                  ),
                ),
            ),  
          ]
        )
      );
  }
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution that I can do:
Pass the default value to sub page, and sub page can update the main tab page.

Sub tab:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class Tab1SubTab1 extends StatefulWidget {
  Tab1SubTab1(this.blockText,this.updateString);
  String blockText;
  final void Function(String) updateString;
  String input;
  @override
  _Tab1SubTab1 createState() => _Tab1SubTab1(blockText,updateString);
  
}

class _Tab1SubTab1 extends State<Tab1SubTab1> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  _Tab1SubTab1(this.blockText,updateString);
  String updateString = '';
  String blockText;
  TextEditingController blockController=new TextEditingController();
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    blockController.text=blockText;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Card(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
                Row( 
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Block:', textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                        fontSize: 25),
                      ),                
                    ]
                  ),
                  Container(              
                    width: 250.0,
                    child: TextField(
                    controller: blockController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Block:',
                  ),
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    widget.updateString(val);
                  }
                ),
            ),  
          ]
        )
      );
  }
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Tab page:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import './tab1.dart';
import './tab1SubTab1.dart';

class TabPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabPages createState() => _TabPages();
}

class _TabPages extends State<TabPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TextEditingController doorNumberController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController blockController = new TextEditingController();
  String test='tre';
  List<Widget> _checkingForm = <Widget>[];
  List<Widget> _subTab1 = <Widget>[];
  int bottomTabSelect=0;
  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(text: 'Room'),
    Tab(text: 'Floor'),
  ];

  int _checkingIndex = 1;

  void _addChecking() {
    _checkingForm = List.from(_checkingForm)
      ..add(Tab1());

    setState(() {
      _checkingIndex += 1;
    });
  }
  
  void _addSubTab1() {
    _subTab1 = List.from(_subTab1)
      ..add(Tab1SubTab1(test,updateString));
    setState(() {
 
    });
  }

  updateString(String ans){
     blockController.text=ans; 
     print(blockController.text);
  }

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
    _addChecking();
    _addSubTab1();
  }

 @override
 void dispose() {
   _tabController.dispose();
   super.dispose();
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: myTabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
            children: [
              ListView(
                children: <Widget>[  
                  Text('Add the room number',textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                      fontSize: 25),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle,color: Colors.lightBlue),
                    onPressed: () {
                        _addChecking();
                      },
                    ),   
                    Column(
                      children:_checkingForm,
                  ),    
                ]
              ),
              ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child: new Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: 50.0,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.lightBlue),
                    child:new Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            print("Container clicked");
                            setState(() {
                              bottomTabSelect=0;
                            });
                          },
                          child:Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  if(bottomTabSelect==0)
                                  Text(
                                    'Main Block',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 30.0,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  if(bottomTabSelect!=0)                                  
                                  Text(
                                    'Main Block',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 22.0,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              )
                            )
                          ),
                          GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            print("Container clicked");
                            setState(() {
                              bottomTabSelect=1;
                            });
                          },                          
                          child:Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  if(bottomTabSelect==1)
                                  Text(
                                    'Other',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 30.0,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  if(bottomTabSelect!=1)                                  
                                  Text(
                                    'Other',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 22.0,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              )
                            )
                          ),                        
                        ]
                      )
                    //child: new Text(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toString()),
                    )
                  ), 
                    Text('Floor:', textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                      fontSize: 25),
                    ),
                      Container(              
                            width: 250.0,
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: doorNumberController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                labelText: 'Floor:',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),  
                      if(bottomTabSelect==1)
                        Tab1SubTab1(blockController.text,updateString),
                    ]
              ),
            ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```